# Using PHP-Data (Objects) in JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php-function to fetch events as objects and I want to add them to my existing ul-list via JQuery. I want to transfer the php-variable to JQuery and want to iterate this variable to build up the HTML. I tried it with this one:

```
$pastEvents = event::getPastEvents($team);
var test = { pastEvents : '<?php echo $pastEvents; ?>' };
for (obj in test.pastEvents) {          
    console.log(obj);
}
```

The result i get is only 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,... in the console. The var_dump from PHP looks like this:

```
array(8) { [0]=> object(game)#10 (17) { ["creatorid":protected]=> int(1) ["tid":protected]=> int(1) ["eid":protected]=> int(12) ["art":protected]=> int(1) ["spielart":protected]=> int(1) ["zeitpunkt":protected]=> string(19) "2012-02-28 11:20:00" ["zeit":protected]=> string(19) "2012-02-18 11:21:50"
```

How can i access the objects from PHP? How can i iterate the variable correctly, that i can access the data like obj.creatorid ... ?

Thanks!

P.S: I could solve this by using jquery's ajax-function - but before the user clicks i already have the data available - so the ajax-request is needless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use php method json_encode() to convert to json.

```
echo json_encode( $array);
```

Then in jQuery ( using ajax)

```
$.getJSON( url, function(data){
   console.log( data)// log the whole json object to console
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, i want to debug this step by step and my first result after "echo json_encode($pastEvents);" is "[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]" -> how can that be?

Comment: very strange since var_dump showed properly. Need php5 but it would have failed if json_encode wasn't a function. Don't understand all the empty objects ..sorry

Comment: I now tried it with this:
 for (var i = 0, len = test.length; i < len; ++i) {
        var even = test[i];
        alert(even.creatorid);
    }
len is 8, that's correct. But alerts have just the result "undefined". Puh, that's frustrating :(

Comment: GOT IT!!! It was hidden somewhere in my brain! The variables in the classes must be public and not protected. Now it works :) thanks!

Comment: alert will not display an object...use browser console to log to, will save you a lot of development time learning to use it and it's not hard

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JSON. Look up the JSON and the PHP functions json_encode and json_decode.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON possibilites. Convert your php data to JSON. That can be easily understood from Javascript.

```
json_encode($myData);
json_decode($myData);
```

To read, JSON, in Javascript, simply access it as an object.

```
myObject.myField
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried it like this:   echo json_encode($pastEvents); but the result is "[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]" -> but the var_dump of $pastEvents is the result from above. How can that be...